# MySQL: how to restrict SUM query by some data?

Tags: php, mysql, sum

I have a query like this :

```
SELECT DATE(Inspection_datetime) AS Date,Line,TRIM(Model) AS Model, Lot_no,
    COUNT(Serial_number) AS Qty
FROM inspection_report 
WHERE Line LIKE 'FA 06' AND MONTH(Inspection_datetime) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE)
GROUP BY DATE(Inspection_datetime), TRIM(Model),Line,Lot_no
```

result:

```
   Date     Line    Model      Lot_no  Qty                 
2012-10-19  FA 06   KD-X30EED   012A    1
2012-10-21  FA 06   KD-R446UD   024A    20
2012-10-21  FA 06   KD-R446UD   026A    25
2012-10-22  FA 06   KD-R430JD   052A    20
2012-10-22  FA 06   KD-R446UD   026A    15
2012-10-22  FA 06   KD-R540JD   025A    30
2012-10-23  FA 06   KD-R540JD   025A    10
2012-10-23  FA 06   KD-R540JD   027A    2
```

how to do if i want to `SUM` the qty until this data:

```
2012-10-22  FA 06   KD-R446UD   026A    15
```

I've tried this:

```
SELECT SUM(X.Qty) AS QTY
FROM (
    SELECT DATE(Inspection_datetime) AS Date,Line,TRIM(Model) AS Model, Lot_no,     COUNT(Serial_number) AS Qty
    FROM inspection_report 
    WHERE Line LIKE 'FA 06' AND MONTH(Inspection_datetime) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE)
    GROUP BY DATE(Inspection_datetime), TRIM(Model),Line,Lot_no) AS X
WHERE ??????????
```

I want the result Like:

```
|Qty |
+----+       
|81  |
```

---

EDIT

if I choose the data stop counting at `2012-10-21   FA 06   KD-R446UD   026A    25`
i will  get `Qty =46`
if this problem impossible to do with MySQL Query, how to do with PHP?

Comment: how do you determine stop at that particular row? if by number of rows, you could use LIMIT 5

Comment: i try using MAX(Date), but the query counting all data in same date.

Comment: @sel:no, it's not stop by particular row (row id), but i want it stop by selected data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use running total variable, like this:

```
SET @total = 0;
SELECT
    (@total := @total + X.qty) AS qty,
    X.Model
FROM (
    SELECT
        DATE(Inspection_datetime) AS Date,
        Line,
        TRIM(Model) AS Model,
        Lot_no,
        COUNT(Serial_number) AS Qty
    FROM inspection_report
    WHERE Line LIKE 'FA 06'
      AND MONTH(Inspection_datetime) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE)
    GROUP BY 1, 3, 2, 4
) AS X
WHERE @total <= 81
```

Comment: what's the meaning of `GROUP BY 1,3,2,4` ?

Comment: This GROUP BY is the same as yours, just shorter. I still don't quite understand your stop criteria - is it by date, by number of rows, by particular record, by max running total?

Comment: I ran the first query, so i can get the array data as above. But then I need to SUM the qty which will stop the counting until the selected data of array result.

Comment: If you know at what record to stop, you should simply use LIMIT n. Also, you can summarize your data in your script by continuosly fetching more rows and stop when you see fit. At any rate, SQL does not guarantee ordering (unless you ORDER BY), and it was not designed for these kind of tasks.